# Как редактировать сохраняемый поток?

Tags: node.js

Сохраняю поток с микрофона на сервер, за основу взял это решение:
https://github.com/gabrielpoca/browser-pcm-stream

Вкратце:

- забирается поток с микрофона
- через binaryjs передается на сервак
- на серваке создается wav файл (fs.createWriteStream)
- поток из binaryjs передается через pipe в wav-файл

Файл сохраняется и прослушивается.

Вопрос: как отредактировать сохраняемый поток?

Пробовал так:

```
var wav = require('wav');
...
file = new wav.FileWriter('out.wav', options);
...
file._write = function(chunk, enc, next) {
  for(var i=0;i<chunk.length;i++) {
    chunk[i] += 5;
  }
  next();
}
...
```

После этого файл перестал заполняться, ошибок не выдает, ощущение что я затер что-то во _write, исходников не нашел.

Как правильно редактировать передаваемые потоки?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать специализированные npm модули, например, [node-core-audio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-core-audio) или [audiolib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/audiolib).

Чтобы создавать кастомные потоки для редактирования данных используйте [stream.Transform](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform_1).

Comment: не нашел необходимого функционала в предложенных Вами модулях, мой вопрос не столько о audio, сколько о streams

Comment: @ДенисВоронов обновил ответ